# repeated random sampling; sampling distribution of the sample median

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
population = 10000
repeat = 400
samplesize_list = [[10, 15, 25], [20, 30, 50], [30, 45, 75]]
label_list = ['50', '100', '150']
std_list = [500, 600, 700]
mean_list = [2000, 3000, 4000]
repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in range(len(samplesize_list)):
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for i in range(repeat):
        sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list[i], std_list[i], size)
        repeat.median[I] = np.median(sample_data)
plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
sns.distplot(repeat_median, color = 'blue', label = label_list[j])
plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.show()
```

need help with a question on repeated random sampling! consider a population size of 10,000 people comprising 3 age groups: age '1-10' of 2000 people, age '11-20' of 3000 people and age '21-30' of 5000 people each normally distributed as follows: age '1-10': mean = 2000, std dev = 500, age '11-20': mean = 3000, std dev = 600 and age '21-30': mean = 4000, std dev = 700.

objetive: perform repeated random sampling of size 50, 100 & 150 from the population and find the sampling distribution of sample median monthly salary. instruction: do it with 400 repeated random sampling outcomes and visualise the sampling distribution simulated.

note: age composition in each sample must be proportionate to the age composition In the population e.g.: in a sample size of 50, no. of people in the age group '1-10' must be 2000/10000 * 50 = 10

I can't seem to get the answer, not sure where I went wrong!

what I should get:

3 graphs - size50, 100, 150 visualising the sampling distribution of the sample median in each sample size respectively taking into account the age-composition of each of the sample size.

Comment: ah I've read through that. I think the concept is similar but I have issues with the nested list and complexity of this question

Comment: I’m pretty sure I could get you the desired output with the math end, but if I did that could you handle the plotting on your own? that part I can’t do

Comment: I think I can! that would be a lot of help